# Skip intermediate classes in hierarchy inheritance with boost::serialization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-serialization

Context: I have a tree-like structure representing a AST of Expr that I want to serialize using `boost::serialization`. The main issue is that all classes have non default constructors  and const children. To overcome this issue, I followed the doc and overloaded `load_construct_data` and `save_construct_data` (which end up doing all the work).

My question is about the `Mul` class within the code. To factorize code, I developed a template class `Op2` that is used to define operators such as *Add* or `Mul` (only `Mul` is shown here) through CRTP on these classes. In `Mul::serialize`, I directly register `Expr` as base class of `Mul`and completely skip `Op2`. **The code works, valgrind is happy, but is it correct ? Or does boost::serialization require to ave the complete class hierarchy ?**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//forward declaration of my structs
struct Expr;
struct Mul;
struct Int;

//forward declarations of custom boost functions to friend them in the class
namespace b_ser = boost::serialization;
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <class Archive>
void load_construct_data(Archive &ar, Mul *e, const unsigned int);

template <class Archive>
void save_construct_data(Archive &ar, const Mul *a, const unsigned int);

template <class Archive>
void load_construct_data(Archive &ar, Int *e, const unsigned int);

template <class Archive>
void save_construct_data(Archive &ar, const Int *a, const unsigned int);


} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

//memory manager
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>> pool;

// AST
struct Expr {
  virtual ~Expr() {}
  virtual std::vector<Expr const *> children() const = 0;
  virtual std::string identity() const = 0;
  void print(int p) const {
    std::cout << std::setw(p) << ' ';
    std::cout << identity() << "\n";

    for (auto a_kid : children()) {
      a_kid->print(p + 2);
    }
  }

  void self_register() const {

    if (std::find_if(pool.begin(), pool.end(), [this](auto const &stored_ptr) {
          return this == stored_ptr.get();
        }) == pool.end()) {
      pool.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Expr>(const_cast<Expr *>(this)));
    }
    for (auto ptr : children()) {
      ptr->self_register();
    }
  }
private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {}

};

struct Int : Expr {
  int const n;
  std::vector<Expr const *> children() const override { return {}; }
  std::string identity() const override {
    return "Int[" + std::to_string(n) + "]@";
  }
  Int(int nn) : n(nn) {}

  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar &boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this);
  }
  template <class Archive>
  friend void b_ser::save_construct_data(Archive &ar, const Int *i,
                                         const unsigned int) {
    ar << i->n;
  }
  template <class Archive>
  friend void b_ser::load_construct_data(Archive &ar, Int *i,
                                         const unsigned int) {
    int n;
    ar >> n;
    ::new (i) Int(n);
  }
};

template <class T> struct Op2 : Expr {
  std::vector<Expr const *> children() const override { return {l, r}; }
  std::string identity() const override { return T::message; }
  Op2(Expr const *ll, Expr const *rr) : l(ll), r(rr) {}

protected:
  Expr const *l;
  Expr const *r;
};
struct Mul : Op2<Mul> {
  using Op2::Op2;
  static auto const constexpr message = "Mul";

private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar &boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this);
  }
  template <class Archive>
  friend void b_ser::save_construct_data(Archive &ar, const Mul *a,
                                         const unsigned int) {
    ar << a->l;
    ar << a->r;
  }

  template <class Archive>
  friend void b_ser::load_construct_data(Archive &ar, Mul *e,
                                         const unsigned int) {
    Expr *l, *r;
    ar >> l;
    ar >> r;
    ::new (e) Mul(l, r);
    e->self_register();
  }
};

template <class T, class... Args> T *store(Args... args) {
  auto to_store = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  auto raw_ptr = to_store.get();
  pool.push_back(std::move(to_store));

  return raw_ptr;
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Expr)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Int)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Mul)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  {

    auto deux = store<Int>(2);
    auto trois = store<Int>(3);
    auto m_23 = store<Mul>(trois, deux);
    auto quatre = store<Int>(4);

    auto root = store<Mul>(m_23, quatre);
    Expr *e_root = root;
    root->print(2);
    std::ofstream of("arxiv");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(of);
    oa << e_root;
  }
  std::cout << "==================="
            << "\n";
  {
    std::ifstream isf("arxiv");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive is(isf);
    Expr *expr;
    is >> expr;
    expr->print(2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I conclude you [must be using MSVC](http://rextester.com/JDME53734) since your code is not valid standard C++.

Fixing things shows it appears to work properly on [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15a3428f1a5f7eff) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/092f68e30b8cfaf8).

> Enabling AddressSanitizer quickly reveals errors that I /believe/ might originate in the singleton code deep inside Boost Serialization. I'll ignore it for now.

Due to those errors, I looked at this a long time, trying to see whether the code was to blame.

While doing so, I found that many things could be made a lot simpler.

- you can do without construct-data if you just add *private* default constructors for serialization purposes.

  The important thing about your classes are the invariants, and it's easy to prove that invariants are kept across deserialization this way.
- you can do without the subclasses for each binary operator, because they add literally no behaviour. Consider providing the `message` constant out-of-band
- instead of making a `vector<unique_ptr>` you can use a pointer container that implicitly owns its elements. This makes e.g. looking up equivalent pointers a *lot* easier:

  ```
  namespace memory_management {
      struct address_less {
          bool operator()(Expr const& a, Expr const& b) const { return &a < &b; }
      };

      static boost::ptr_set<Expr, address_less> pool;
  }

  void Expr::self_register() { memory_management::pool.insert(this); }
  ```

All in all things are much shorter:

```
// AST
struct Expr {
    virtual ~Expr() = default;
    virtual std::vector<Expr const *> children() const { return {}; }
    virtual std::string identity() const = 0;
    void print(int p) const {
        std::cout << std::setw(p) << ' ';
        std::cout << identity() << "\n";

        for (auto a_kid : children()) {
            a_kid->print(p + 2);
        }
    }

  protected:
    Expr() { self_register(); }
  private:
    void self_register();

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &, unsigned) {}
};

namespace memory_management {
    struct address_less {
        bool operator()(Expr const& a, Expr const& b) const { return &a < &b; }
    };

    static boost::ptr_set<Expr, address_less> pool;
}

void ::Expr::self_register() { memory_management::pool.insert(this); }

struct Int : Expr {
    std::string identity() const override { return "Int[" + std::to_string(n) + "]@"; }
    Int(int nn) : n(nn) {}

  private:
    int const n = 0;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    Int() = default;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this) 
           & const_cast<int&>(n);
    }
};

namespace Tags {
    struct Mul;
    struct Div;
    struct Plus;
    struct Minus;
    template <typename T> constexpr char const* const message        = "Unknown";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Mul>   = "Mul";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Div>   = "Div";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Plus>  = "Plus";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Minus> = "Minus";
}

template <class T> struct Op2 : Expr {
    std::vector<Expr const *> children() const override { return { l, r }; }
    std::string identity() const override { return Tags::message<T>; }
    Op2(Expr *ll, Expr *rr) : l(ll), r(rr) {}

  protected:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    Op2() = default;
    Expr *l = nullptr;
    Expr *r = nullptr;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this)
           & l & r;
    }
};

using Mul   = Op2<Tags::Mul>;
using Div   = Op2<Tags::Div>;
using Plus  = Op2<Tags::Plus>;
using Minus = Op2<Tags::Minus>;
```

### Bonus: A DSL For AST Building

I thought it would be nicer to be able to say:

```
Expr const* root((as_expr(3) * 2) + 5 + (as_expr(7) / 25));
```

So, let's do that:

```
namespace builder {
    struct Atom {
        Atom(Expr* expr) : expr(expr)  {}
        Atom(int i) : expr(new Int(i)) {}
        Expr* expr;

        explicit operator Expr const*() const { return expr; }
    };

    template <typename T>
    Atom as_expr(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }

    Atom operator+(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Plus(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator-(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Minus(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator*(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Mul(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator/(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Div(a.expr, b.expr); }
}
```

### LIVE DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18cc9cff08b370cb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_set.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// AST
struct Expr {
    virtual ~Expr() = default;
    virtual std::vector<Expr const *> children() const { return {}; }
    virtual std::string identity() const = 0;
    void print(int p) const {
        std::cout << std::setw(p) << ' ';
        std::cout << identity() << "\n";

        for (auto a_kid : children()) {
            a_kid->print(p + 2);
        }
    }

  protected:
    Expr() { self_register(); }
  private:
    void self_register();

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &, unsigned) {}
};

namespace memory_management {
    struct address_less {
        bool operator()(Expr const& a, Expr const& b) const { return &a < &b; }
    };

    static boost::ptr_set<Expr, address_less> pool;
}

void ::Expr::self_register() { memory_management::pool.insert(this); }

struct Int : Expr {
    std::string identity() const override { return "Int[" + std::to_string(n) + "]@"; }
    Int(int nn) : n(nn) {}

  private:
    int const n = 0;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    Int() = default;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this) 
           & const_cast<int&>(n);
    }
};

namespace Tags {
    struct Mul;
    struct Div;
    struct Plus;
    struct Minus;
    template <typename T> constexpr char const* const message        = "Unknown";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Mul>   = "Mul";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Div>   = "Div";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Plus>  = "Plus";
    template <>           constexpr char const* const message<Minus> = "Minus";
}

template <class T> struct Op2 : Expr {
    std::vector<Expr const *> children() const override { return { l, r }; }
    std::string identity() const override { return Tags::message<T>; }
    Op2(Expr *ll, Expr *rr) : l(ll), r(rr) {}

  protected:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    Op2() = default;
    Expr *l = nullptr;
    Expr *r = nullptr;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Expr>(*this)
           & l & r;
    }
};

using Mul   = Op2<Tags::Mul>;
using Div   = Op2<Tags::Div>;
using Plus  = Op2<Tags::Plus>;
using Minus = Op2<Tags::Minus>;

namespace builder {
    struct Atom {
        Atom(Expr* expr) :expr(expr){}
        Atom(int i) :expr(new Int(i)){}
        Expr* expr;

        explicit operator Expr const*() const { return expr; }
    };

    template <typename T>
    Atom as_expr(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }

    Atom operator+(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Plus(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator-(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Minus(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator*(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Mul(a.expr, b.expr); }
    Atom operator/(Atom a, Atom b) { return new Div(a.expr, b.expr); }
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Expr)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Int)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Mul)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Div)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Plus)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Minus)

int main() {
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    {
        using builder::as_expr;

        Expr const* root((as_expr(3) * 2) + 5 + (as_expr(7) / 25));

        root->print(2);
        std::ofstream of("arxiv");

        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(of);
        oa << root;
    }
    std::cout << "===================\n";
    {
        std::ifstream isf("arxiv");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive is(isf);
        Expr *expr = nullptr;
        is >> expr;
        expr->print(2);
    }

    memory_management::pool.clear(); // no memory leaks
}
```

Prints

```
  Plus
    Plus
      Mul
        Int[3]@
        Int[2]@
      Int[5]@
    Div
      Int[7]@
      Int[25]@
===================
  Plus
    Plus
      Mul
        Int[3]@
        Int[2]@
      Int[5]@
    Div
      Int[7]@
      Int[25]@
```

Comment: I'm not using MSVC, the original code compiles just fine with g++-7 and C++14 enabled on ubuntu 16.04. I'm sorry but I screw up my original code. Attributes should be const pointers to non-const object (ie T * const ptr). That's how they are in the real code and how they should have been here. Hence adding a default constructor does not help as the compiler complains about const members not being initialized. The subclasses are here to make the code as close as possible to the real one but your example is nice. I'll consider ptr_set. Finally, you did not answer the original question but thx :)

Comment: And i explained, at each stop, how that happened. I suppose if you insist on complicating things you can probably extrapolate from here. I know the arguments in favour of const attributes but they have a cost. Your choice

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand the first two sentences of your last comment.

Comment: Okay, home now. Let me reiterate, there is nothing wrong with your code - it works because the intermediates are never (de)serialized). I stated it a bit implicit, because I spent a lot of time finding out whether the Asan messages originate from your code (it doesn't, as I stated).

Comment: I happen to value simple code, and my sample indeed achieves a multiple of the original code in 80% of the length. In fact I'd simplify further, and here's the code with `Expr *const` data members: [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c463edcf280a283d).

Comment: My take on the whole thing would probably look like this: [less than half the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85cd657a93bb7343) - value-semantics, const-correctness and no manual memory management in sight. (Bonus: [with `children()` implemented](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b838ca746b2e609d))